# Running expect script on EC2 hangs, but runs successfully when manually invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, expect

I'm writing an `expect` script to start an SSH tunnel.

It gets run on EC2 when the instance starts, as part of the deployment which creates the script from a `.ebextensions` config file.

When the script is run, it always gets stuck at this point:

`Enter passphrase for key '/home/ec2-user/id_data_app_rsa':`

If I run the same script manually on the server it succeeds and i can see the tunnel process running.

`ps aux | grep ssh`

`root 19046 0.0 0.0 73660 1068 ? Ss   16:58   0:00 ssh -i /home/ec2-user/id_data_app_rsa -p222 -vfN -L 3306:X.X.X.X:3306 root@X.X.X.X`

I can verify that the script is reading the `SSH_PASSPHRASE` correctly by printing it to the console.

```
   set password $::env(SSH_PASSPHRASE)
   send_user "retrieved env variable : $password "
```

This is the debug output I get from the EC2 logs:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ec2-user/id_data_app_rsa': 
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0
```

I'm baffled as to why it's getting no further here when the EC2 deployer runs, but it continues normally when run manually.

This is the script in `.ebextensions`, the script itself starts at `#!/usr/bin/expect`:

```
files:

  "/scripts/createTunnel.sh" :
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
   #!/usr/bin/expect
   exp_internal 1
   set timeout 60
   # set variables
   set password $::env(SSH_PASSPHRASE)
   send_user "retrieved env variable : $password "
   spawn -ignore HUP ssh -i /home/ec2-user/id_data_app_rsa -p222 -vfN -L 3306:X.X.X.X:3306 root@X.X.X.X

   expect {
    "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\n" }
    -re "(.*)assphrase"     { sleep 1; send -- "$password\n" }
    -re "(.*)data_app_rsa"  { sleep 1; send -- "$password\n" }
    -re "(.*)assword:"      { sleep 1; send -- "$password\n" }

    timeout     { send_user "un-able to login: timeout\n"; return }
    "denied"    { send_user "\nFatal Error: denied \n"}
    eof         { send_user "Closed\n" ; return }
}
interact
```

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` at the beginning of your script to get more debug information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally resolved this. There were two things that seemed to be at issue:

- Changing the final `interact` to `expect eof`.
- Trimming down the
  `expect` pattern matching as much as possible.

We noticed in testing that expect seemed to be matching falsely, sending a password, for example, when it should have been sending a 'yes' matching on the 'yes/no' prompt.

This is the final script we ended up with in case it's useful to anyone else:

```
     #!/usr/bin/expect
     exp_internal 1
     set timeout 60
     # set variables
     set password $::env(SSH_TUNNEL_PASSPHRASE)
     spawn -ignore HUP ssh -i /home/ec2-user/id_data_rsa -p222 -vfN   -L 3306:X.X.X.X:3306 root@X.X.X.X
     expect {
         "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
         "Enter passphrase" { sleep 2; send -- "$password\r"; sleep 2; exit }
     }
     expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
set password $::env(SSH_PASSPHRASE)
```

and the way shell works with environment variables.  When the script is invoked, you assume your environment variables are set.  Depending on how the script is invoked, $::env(SSH_PASSPHRASE) may not be set, resulting in the variable to be null/blank.   When init scripts (or cloud-init) are run, they are not run with the environment of a login shell.  So you should not assume that .profile or /etc/profile environment variables are set, but rather source or set them explicitly.

A possible solution may be

```
. ~ec2-user/.profile /path/to/above.script
```

Comment: Just getting to test this now, but unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the issue. I can print the value of the environment variable to the console and see it has been correctly picked up by the script.

Comment: even when it fails the value of password is correct?  CR/LF and nulls?

Comment: The value of the password is correct. I'm not sure what you mean by your second question: "CR/LF and nulls?"